# double event when opening modal more than once

Tags: javascript

I have a modal that when I open it, it detects a single click, until there everything is correct, the problem is when I close it and open it again, it begins to detect a double event (click) and if I close and open it again detects 3 events (clicks), it is made in vanilla js

**HTML:**

```
<div id="modal-container-gestion-documental" class="modal-container-gestion-documental">
  <div class="modal-gestion-documental">
    <div class="cabecera-modal">
      <h3 class="">Gestión Documental</h3>
      <a href="#" class="cerrar-gestion-documental">CERRAR</a>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="div-padre-gestor">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
const modalContainerGestionDocumental = document.getElementById(
 "modal-container-gestion-documental"
);

document.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
   if (e.target.matches(".abrir-gestion-documental")) {
     e.preventDefault();
     modalContainerGestionDocumental.classList.add("show-modal");
   }
   if (e.target.matches(".cerrar-gestion-documental")) {
     e.preventDefault();
     modalContainerGestionDocumental.classList.remove("show-modal");
   }
}
```

**Css:**

```
.modal-container-gestion-documental {
  z-index: 2;
   margin: 0 auto;
   display: flex;
   background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: center;
   position: fixed;
   pointer-events: none;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   height: 100vh;
   width: 100vw;
   opacity: 0;
}

.modal-gestion-documental{
  margin-top: 75px;
   padding: 3rem;
   background-color: #fff;
   width: 85%;
   height: 88%;
   border-radius: 5px;
   box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.show-modal {
   pointer-events: auto;
   opacity: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on where you have this `document.addEventListener("click..` part of the code. Based on your description, it seems like that listener is being triggered every time the modal opens/closes.

Make sure to get the listener to be triggered only once on page load. If it's unavoidable, you can `removeEventListener` whenever the modal closes.

Comment: I had another addEventListener ("click") in another part of the code, I had done it like this to modulate but unifying the code a bit it was solved